# Elasticsearch Range aggregation bucket doc_count not consistent with Range field types

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I need Elasticsearch Range aggregation `doc_count` consistent with the Range field query. The field is of type float.

The challenge I am getting is getting consistent count results with Range aggregation and Range field query.

**Elasticsearch Range aggregation:**

```
GET /ranking/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "score_ranges": {
      "range": {
        "field": "field_rating",
        "keyed": true, 
        "ranges": [
          { "to":4.99 },
          { "from": 4.99, "to": 9.99 },
          { "from": 9.99, "to": 19.99 },
          { "from": 19.99, "to": 29.99 },
          { "from": 29.99 }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Range field query:**

```
GET /ranking/_search&search_type=_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "field_rating": {
            "gte": "1.00",
            "lte": "4.99"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have read in the documentation this -

> "Note that this aggregation includes the from value and excludes the to value for each range"

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html

I wonder if there is a way to get the aggregates consistent with the Range query.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the filter should return the same documents/count as are in the first bucket. As the documentation you cited states: the bucket excludes the `to` value, so documents with a rating value of 4.99 are **not** contained in the bucket. But you filter counts them in by using `lte`.

so you'd need to change that to `"lt": "4.99"`

Second issue: your filter does not consider any documents with a rating below 1.0 whereas the first bucket has no lower bound set. That's fine if that value never will below 1.0, but otherwise this is causing different results as well.

Comment: The use case requires the use of `lte`. How can make the range include the `to` value? I tried to add a plus +1 on the `to` value but still got weird results.

The value will never be below 1.0.